# Bash script for opening terminal, taking user input for performing a task, and then closing terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to open an application if it is installed, or otherwise first install and the run it. I have two scripts. The first script (script1) checks if the program is installed; if it is not installed, it opens x-terminal-emulator (x4ce4-terminal) and runs the second script (script2):

```
#!/bin/bash

if type PACKAGENAME >/dev/null 2>&1
then 
    PACKAGENAME
else 
    x-terminal-emulator -e 'sh -ic "/path/script2.sh; exec bash"' 
fi
exit
```

Script2 asks the user if s/he wants to install and run the program, otherwise it flashes a goodbye message.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "PACKAGENAME is not installed. Do you want to install and use now? Type y for yes or n for no: "
read response
if [ "$response" != "${response#[Yy]}" ] ;
then
    echo 'Installing PACKAGENAME...' && sudo aptitude install -y PACKAGENAME && PACKAGENAME
else
    echo 'Good bye' 
fi
```

for both Y/y or N/n, the terminal should close. However, though script2 is working correctly, I am unable to make the terminal close. Would greatly appreciate help and suggestions. Corollary question: Is is possible to flash the "Good bye" message for say, 5 seconds, and then close the terminal? Thanks

Comment: Why do you start an interactive shell from the first script? I would remove `exec bash`. If you want a delay before the terminal exits, insert a `sleep` call or read a dummy value from the user and ask them to press `Return`. Also, it looks a bit odd to invoke `sh` to invoke the shell script.  Why not just `x-terminal-emulator -e /path/script2.sh`?

Comment: @they... Yes, that's also possible. But my main issue is exiting the terminal. Any pointers to that?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned two possibilities in my previous comment.

Comment: Usually when the process hosted by the terminal exits, the terminal also closes. However the user can have configuration options which keep it open. Check the documentation for x-terminal-emulator, you may be able to override this with a flag.